# React hook: used in render method (Error: Invalid hook call)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to react, and I want to build a website that could display pdf.

I have downloaded the pdf viewer by "npm install react-pdf", and based on the simple example https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pdf, I write the following code.

```
(import stuff)

class pdfViewer extends Component {
   pdfView = () => {
        const [numPages, setNumPages] = useState(null);
        const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(1);

        return (
            <div>
                <Document
                    file={eggPdf}
                    onLoadSuccess={({ numPages }) => {
                        setNumPages(numPages);
                    }}
                >
                    <Page pageNumber={pageNumber} />
                </Document>
                <p>Page {pageNumber} of {numPages}</p>
            </div>
        );
       }

  render(){
        const pdfViwer = this.pdfView();
        return(
        <div>
           {pdfViwer}
        </div>
        );

}

(export)
```

It shows error: **Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:...**

How should I modify this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hooks are for functional componenst not for classes. If you want to use hooks, convert the class to function or use state instead of hook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should either use function or class components. If you want to use hooks, you need to use function components like so:

```
(import stuff)

  const PdfView = () => {
        const [numPages, setNumPages] = useState(null);
        const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(1);

        return (
            <div>
                <Document
                    file={eggPdf}
                    onLoadSuccess={({ numPages }) => {
                        setNumPages(numPages);
                    }}
                >
                    <Page pageNumber={pageNumber} />
                </Document>
                <p>Page {pageNumber} of {numPages}</p>
            </div>
        );
       }

export default PdfView;
```

Now you can use this component where you want in your app.